# Sending QR code from Google Sheets to email address

Tags: google-apps-script, qr-code, gmail-api

I have a simple Google Form setup to capture data, pull it into a doc and then send a confirmation email to the respondee.

I've recently been using the Sheets method for automatically creating QR codes in the form response sheet using =image("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl="&K2). The information in 'K2' is a very simple 20 digit number and I'd like the QR code to be sent in the confirmation email.

The email uses some very basic HTML and I guessed that the QR code might need it's own `<img>` tag since others bits of data pulled through are just strings but I wouldn't know where to start with the img source. Can anyone suggest the right method for achieving this or if there's an easier alternative? I'm new to Google Apps Script so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is some sample code:

```
function sendQRCode() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // Range (last entry submitted)

for (var i in data){
  var row = data[i];
  var custemail = row[14];
  var qrCode= row[15];

  var mailBody1 = '<p>Hi ' + row[2] + ',<br /><br />Thanks for your response.<br /><br />Here is a QR code with the information you require:</p>' + qrCode + '<p>Kind regards,</p><p>The Team</p>'

  if ((row[9]=="Yes") && (row[13]=="Yes")){
     MailApp.sendEmail(custemail,"Your QR Code",mailBody1,{'htmlBody' :mailBody1,noReply: true});}
 }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? What did you try? I'd imagine you could simply recreate that URL as the img source and specify it in the html body...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap the image (the URL) with an `<img` tag in the email body. Something like `<img src='"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=' + row[10] + '"' />` in the email should work.

Comment: Hi there, this worked perfectly thanks. I figured it out in a moment of clarity while away from the office so probably need to give it a bit more time before posting next time. Thanks again for your help and patience!